# Can you use env var expansion such as %APPDATA% in log4j.properties file?

Tags: java, logging, environment-variables

Can you use an env var expansion such as `%APPDATA%` in `log4j.properties` file?

I need to deploy this file as part of my app and in the following line I want to specify a user specific folder such as %APPDATA%.  Is this possible?

```
log4j.appender.A2.File=%APPDATA%/mylog.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference environment variables directly, but you can refer to Java "system properties."

For example, when starting up your application, set the system property on the command line:

```
java -Dapp.data="%APPDATA%" ...
```

Inside your log4j.properties file, reference the system property you set on the command line:

```
log4j.appender.A2.File=${app.data}/mylog.log
```

Comment: Due to the architecture of the system I cannot create any Java system variables in the manner you have described. Are there any built-in Java system properties that I could use?  What about `user.dir`?

Comment: %APPDATA% = %USERPROFILE%\Application Data = System.getProperty("user.home")\Application Data

Comment: Sorry, it is System.getProperty("user.home") = %USERPROFILE%

Comment: @CraigJ Can you set a Windows environment variable? If so, [you could specify this information in the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable,](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) and it will be picked up whenever a JVM is started, as if it were specified on the command line.

Comment: @erickson: `${user.home}/Application Data` worked fine for me. This path resolves to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming` on Win7 which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my `log4j2.xml` configuration file.

```
 <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${sys:user.home}/AppData/Roaming/MyApplication/MyApplication.log" filePattern="${sys:user.home}/AppData/Roaming/MyApplication/MyApplication.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
```